# In which file Terminal.app stores its windows?

Tags: terminal, path

Usually after reboot/crash all Terminal windows are re-open automatically, this time they weren't.

Where (which folder/file) Terminal.app stores the session/information about its windows which suppose to be re-open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is stored in the user's Saved Application State folder, located at:

`/Users/$USER/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Terminal.savedState`